# Is there a Firefox 7 compatible plugin for Aptana Studio 3?

Tags: aptana, aptana3

My installation of Firefox was recently updated to version 7, and I see now that the Aptana Debugger 1.7 extension is not compatible.

It looks like reverting to Firefox 6 may not be an option...it seems they do not keep all of the old versions around.

Is there an update available for the Aptana Debugger extension? Is one in the works that will be compatible with Firefox 7?

Thanks.
Scott

Comment: Response from Aptana via Twitter:

@shammer64 For the immediate moment, the debugger is incompatible, but we hope to have an update in next week or so.